# Unit test dependency injection without actually resolving instances

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm trying to unit test dependency injection. Obviously, this stuff will be tested with good functional tests or QA, but I think it's possible (and better) to test it sooner. The thing is, some of our constructors will do something functional, like look up a config value in the database or on the file system, sometimes with injected dependencies. And then some of the singletons we register will do the same sorts of things.

Our code *only* uses constructor injection, not method or property injection. This makes me think that we can verify that a type can be constructed by just walking the dependency and constructor tree that would be chosen by Autofac, but never actually constructing a type.

This in essence is my question. Has anyone here hijacked Autofac's activator code to not actually *activate* types, but just verify it *could*?

Comment: The problem is that not all things are activated by reflection. For things that are registered as lambdas, performing that analysis (will the lambda run?) isn't as straightforward as just walking a dependency tree.

Answer (score 2):

> some of our constructors will do something functional, like look up a config value in the database or on the file system, sometimes with injected dependencies.

This is the source of your problems. As stated clearly [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), injection constructors should be simple. Any initialization should be either done after the graph is built or before. Especially looking up configuration values is something the class should not be concerned of itself. The Composition Root should load those values and inject them into the classes that require them.

After moving the responsibility of loading configuration values out of the class, it becomes much easier to test such class.